# Return a line of code

Tags: javascript

So I'm using JavaScript to make something to solve simple algebraic expressions. I've got everything for the math part done but I need to run a line of code again. So I've used a conditional branch to determine if the first side of the equation is equal to the second side. If it's equal then the value of the variable is given but if it isn't the same, then the variable is increased by one.

```
function Command() {
var FirstSide = document.getElementById("FirstLine").value;
   var SecondSide = document.getElementById("SecondLine").value;
   var evalLineOne = FirstSide;
   var evalLineTwo = SecondSide;
   var X = 1;
   var MathLineOne = eval(evalLineOne);
   var MathLineTwo = eval(evalLineTwo);
      if (MathLineOne == MathLineTwo)       
          document.getElementById("Reply").innerHTML = X;
      else { 
          X + 1;
      }
```

So this is the code I've used. When using an algebraic expression where the value of X is not 1 the code simply doesn't work. I was assuming this was because I would need to rerun the code from the line of code which defines the value of "X". How would I go back to run this code?

Comment: `X + 1` expression needs to be assigned somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without making a lot of changes to your code, you could call the same function recursively like so:

```
var max = 9999999; //set this to whatever you want
function Command(X) {
   if (typeof X === 'undefined') X = 1;
   if (X > max) return;
   var FirstSide = document.getElementById("FirstLine").value;
   var SecondSide = document.getElementById("SecondLine").value;
   var evalLineOne = FirstSide;
   var evalLineTwo = SecondSide;
   var MathLineOne = eval(evalLineOne);
   var MathLineTwo = eval(evalLineTwo);
   if (MathLineOne == MathLineTwo)       
      document.getElementById("Reply").innerHTML = X;
   else { 
      Command(X+1);
   }
}
```